# Create HashMap with filename as key and filecontent as value

Tags: java, file, hashmap

I have few files in my local folder. I want to store the file-names as the key and the content of the corresponding file as value.

```
HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
hm.put(filename,filecontent);
```

Can someone tell me is this the right way to do?

Comment: yes you can...but better to open only those file which are required at a time.

Answer (score 2):

When storing file contents as a String, you have to make sure the encoding is respected, I would recommend to use byte array instead:

```
Map<String, byte[]> hm = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
```

**Also**: depending on how many files you are manipulating, you may want to consider using **file streams** to avoid keeping everything in memory.

Comment: should be:
Map<String, byte[]> hm = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();

Comment: Yes, even better! Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of steps to what you would like.

I am going to assume you have the filename already as a `String`.

```
HashMap<String, byte[]> hm = new HashMap<String, byte[]>(); //Initialize our hashmap with String as key, and byte array as data (binary data)
FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filename); //Get a stream of the file
byte[] buff = new byte[512]; //A buffer for our read loop
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); //Where to write buff content to, we can convert this into the output byte array with toByteArray()
while(fileStream.read(buff) > 0) { //read 512 bytes of file at a time, until end of file
    byteStream.write(buff); //write buff content to byte stream
}
fileStream.close(); //Close our file handle, if we don't do this we may not be able to see changes!
hm.put(filename, byteStream.toByteArray()); //insert filename and filecontent to hashmap
```

As others have suggested, however, this is less than ideal. You are holding multiple files in memory for an arbitrary length of time. You can eat a lot of ram and not realize it doing this, and quickly run into an out of memory exception.

You would be better off reading the file content only when needed, so there isn't a whole file sitting in your ram for god knows how long. The only plausible reason I could see to store file contents would be if you were reading it a lot, and you could afford the ram to cache the file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Binary Data**

```
HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();    
    final File folder = new File("/home/you/Desktop");
            listFilesForFolder(folder);   

public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            } else {
                String name = fileEntry.getName();
                 byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) fileEntry.length()];
                 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileEntry));
                 dis.readFully(fileData);
                 dis.close();
                 hm.put(name,fileData);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Tested for Zip file for OP:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File file = new File("D:\\try.zip");
        System.out.println(file.length());
        byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        dis.readFully(fileData);
        dis.close();

    }
```

Comment: This will only work with text files. A solution using bytes would work on text as well as binary data.

Comment: This works for only files I need for binary data as well. For example Zip files.